# Difference between Impact vs normal drill bits for Masonary with sufficient BPM impact

Tags: brick, drill-bit, combi

So a Disclaimer - This is not a product review (so please do not misunderstand the intent)

I have got a trades-grade impact drill - [DeWalt DCD795](https://www.dewalt.co.uk/products/dcd795d2-gb--18v-xr-brushless-hammer-drill-driver-2-x-2ah) which has enough torque and impact bpm to drill through pretty much anything up to 13mm for masonary - or so the reviews claim, and the observations I've made over 100s of youtube training videos.

I've got all my [drill bits here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B000P4IQN4/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) (exactly these one)

But I cannot really drill through them fast/easy enough. I tried with 4mm bits (and that's really small) and used it on my brickwall - but it just doesn't go through (even with Hammer action and 2nd Gear). I don't think I need SDS for something as meager  as 4-6mm. And I had trades people who previously did some job for me using these drills (not SDS, unless it was something in the range of 20mm)

My question is - What is the difference that I am encountering here? Surely, millions of homeowners have DIY needs and not everyone is buying an SDS drill, right?

So - Does this have to do with drill bits, or do I have to use something else here?

Comment: "fast/easy enough" How fast do you expect to be drilling through masonry? You're not drilling through soft pine, so it's going to take longer.  What kind of expectations do you have? They may be too high. The key is, are you getting the hole you want? If so, you're golden.

Comment: **many** possible factors - how hard you push, the bit, the condition of the bit (once you dull it, it's dull) different masonry materials (even "brick" - not all brick is even close to "the same")

Comment: Assuming you're using one of those silvery drills on the left side (since those are the masonry bits), your drill is set to "hammer", and high-speed, then I'd expect a 4mm hole to take anywhere from 30 seconds to a minute or so - depending on your luck with the bricks. It might go a bit quicker using a corded (non-SDS) drill - they generally seem to hammer a little harder than the battery-powered ones.

Comment: None of the bits in the set you linked to are for use in "hammer-drill" mode. Furthermore, the masonry bits in that set (the ones on the left in the holder pictured in the link) *are* for masonry... but look cheap and flimsy and suitable for plaster/stucco or other such materials, rather than brick or concrete or stone.

Comment: What you're learning is that hammer drills are absolutely pants for drilling masonry, anything harder than breeze block. Rent an SDS, see the difference.

Comment: Try the highest speed, and pull out regularly so you aren’t clogging the bit with dust. Fwiw, those aren’t the greatest masonry bits, either.

Answer (score -1):

I use the bits in your set called "tile" only for drilling glass and ceramic tile ( no hammer). I have made a few small holes in brick but don't use then on masonry because they are slow. I use what I call masonry bits for masonry hammer applications; they have a carbide inset in the point and a slow( many turns) spiral. That is, I do not see any bits I call normal "masonry" bits in your set. Also , water flushing is a big help ; cooling and flushing cuttings.

Comment: I see no tile bits in that set. I see masonry, wood & metal. Tile bits are pointed - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Professional-Plastic-Cement-Industrial-Strength/dp/B08K2TDHB6/ref=sr_1_7?keywords=Tile+Drill+Bits&qid=1649062591&sr=8-7